# Adding real Admob addvertisements on Flutter App

Tags: flutter, admob, ads

I have added AdMob's ads into my flutter application.it shows adds with a "test ad" tag on it.No impresions.No revenue yet.what should I do? and it only shows in my testing device but not showing other devices. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjpOC.jpg)

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-4881405240833971~497555****"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an adMob project corresponding to your app with ad units
If you already did this, then don't forget to create your own ad in adMob and replace in your code the test ad id by the one you created

There is a [Flutter Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter/#) explaining the whole process of integrating ads, you might want to look at it

Comment: follow the steps. In AdMob console, it counts number of requests.but no rewards

Comment: Does it still display a test ad or a real one ? Are you on emulator or on a real device ? I'm not sure but I think rewards are only for a release version on a real device